# Android ImageReader aquireLatestImage occasionally null

Tags: android

I have an app setup that is able to capture screen content.  However, on occasion, I get a `null` value returned from [aquireLatestImage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html#acquireLatestImage()).  The documentation says it will return "null if no image data is available.".

I'm curious to know what casues no image data to be available?

Edit:  From what I can tell, this occurs most frequently on LG devices...

Edit 2:  The case I'm running into is a null value being returned after it's previously returned valid image values.  And it continues to return null values.  For non LG devices, nulls are occasionally returned.  For LG devices, it seems once it's returned one null the rest will be nulls.

Edit 3:  Including some code

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(displayMetrics );

ImageReader imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);

virtualDisplay = mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("NetCountableVirtualDisplay",
        displayMetrics.widthPixels,
        displayMetrics.heightPixels,
        displayMetrics.densityDpi,
        DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC,
        imageReader.getSurface(),
        null,
        null);
```

Comment: Can you paste some code of yours where you instantiate the `ImageReader` object? The parameters passed to the `newInstance` method like `maxImages` might be important

Comment: @pleft Just added, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says "Returns null if no **new** image is available"
This means you are calling it before it is able to acquire a new image, so instead of wasting resources sending you the same image twice, it just returns null.

Comment: The case I'm running into is a null value being returned after it's previously had values.  And it continues to return null values indefinitely from what I can tell.